# MVC 3 Ajax.beginform submit - causes full postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, ajax.beginform

Hi i am trying to get to grips with ajax.beginform using mvc 3.

I have 2 forms, a HTML.BeginForm which works fine and a Ajax.BeginForm in a partial view. The post of the ajax form is to add notes to the model.

The problem is the ajax submit is submitting the whole page including the HTML.BeginForm at in the main view and not performing the asynchronous post with the note.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong?

Ive look at other questions and have disabled the unobtrusive javascript in web.config etc.

View:

```
<div id="maincontent">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Franchise</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstLine)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstLine)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstLine)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecondLine)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondLine)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecondLine)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Postcode)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Postcode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone)
    </div>
    <p class="clear">
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>

  @Html.Partial("Partial/_AddNote", new Cash4Schools.Domain.Model.Note())

}
```

Partial View:

```
@model Cash4Schools.Domain.Model.Note
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNote", "Franchises", 
  new AjaxOptions {
     HttpMethod = "POST", 
     UpdateTargetId = "note" }, 
     new { id = "ajaxForm" })
     )
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Add a Note</legend>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreationDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreationDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
    </div>

    <p class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNote(Note model)
{
  var franchise = _franchiseRepository.FindById(model.Id);

  franchise.Notes.Add(
    new Note {
      Content = model.Content,
      CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
      CreatedBy = model.CreatedBy,
      Type = NoteType.Franchise
    }
  );

  _franchiseRepository.Save(franchise);

  return PartialView(franchise.Notes);
}
```

HTML Output:

```
<form action="/Franchises/AddNote?Length=10" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#note" id="ajaxForm" method="post">    <fieldset>
    <legend>Add a Note</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Content">Content</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="Content" name="Content" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Content" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="CreationDate">CreationDate</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CreationDate field is required." id="CreationDate" name="CreationDate" type="text" value="01/01/0001 00:00:00" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CreationDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="CreatedBy">CreatedBy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="CreatedBy" name="CreatedBy" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CreatedBy" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <p class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
</form><div id="note"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

    </fieldset>

    @Html.Partial("Partial/_AddNote", new Cash4Schools.Domain.Model.Note())
    --Partial call and therefore, the form within the partial, is embedded 
    --in the main form
}
```

change it to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
    ....
    </fieldset>

}

@Html.Partial("Partial/_AddNote", new Cash4Schools.Domain.Model.Note())
--Partial call outside main form, no longer embedded. Works
```

The embedded form within a form is mucking the works up.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your Reference to the Microsoft libraries there and use only jQuery... Which is what is now used behind the scenes anyways. Enable unobtrusive JavaScript and include the libs as in my blog post here and it should work for you just fine.

http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/unobstrusive-javascript-in-mvc-3-helps.html

Comment: @Admin Tuliper I have altered my forms to use the jquery unbotrusive ajax and switch the appsetting back on - but i still have the same problem -  the page is calling the Edit ActionResult in my controller not the AddNote ActionResult. I will update with the html the ajax.beginform is outputting.